# How to get a folder from CAML Query?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have a List which has a two level hierarchy of folders. Something like this:

```
List
    Folder_1
       SubFolder_1
              Item 1_1_1
              Item 1_1_2
       SubFolder_2
              Item 1_2_1
              Item 1_2_2
              Item 1_2_3
    Folder_2
       SubFolder_1
              Item 2_1_1
              Item 2_1_2
              Item 2_1_3
       SubFolder_2
              Item 2_2_1
              Item 2_2_2
```

I want to add a list item to a folder depending on some criteria. I don't want to loop through all folders as the number of folders is more. So, I thought of running a CAML query to get the folder.

Below CAML Query gives me all folders in the list:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
        <Value Type='int'>0</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

How can I add another condition to the above query so that I can get a specific folder when I know the exact folder name?

Comment: Small correction on your CAML Query, if you check the values for the "FSObjType" you'll see that 0 returns all the files but 1 will return all the folders

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filesystemobjecttype.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using FileLeafRef or FileDirRef as the name. I don't think that will work, though, as you need an SPFolder object to add a list Item to it and CAML queries return SPListItemCollection. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862315.aspx for a list of some fieldnames you could try.

Since you know the name (and I presume the whole path) of the folder, why don't you use the [SPWeb.GetFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461547.aspx) method to get the folder and then add an item using that folder object?

The following two links might be useful:

- http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/12/add-list-item.html
- http://darrinbishop.com/blog/archive/2007/04/08/41.aspx

A snippet from the second link:

> Creating a SPListItem in a SPFolder
>   Using the OM
>
> Creating a folder (SPFolder) using the
>   WSS 3.0 object model is simple.
>   Creating a list item (SPListItem) in a
>   list is simple as well. It took me
>   awhile and a number of emails to
>   finally create a list item in an
>   existing folder.  So here is the code
>   to save you some time.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://[ServerName/sitename]"); 
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(); 
SPList list = web.Lists["Tasks"]; 

SPFolder f = web.GetFolder("http://[ServerName/sitename]/Lists/Tasks/Test" );
if(f.Exists)
{
   SPListItemCollection itemColl = list.Items;

   SPListItem item = itemColl.Add(f.ServerRelativeUrl, 
                                  SPFileSystemObjectType.File,
                                  null);

   item["Title"] = "Added from OM";
   item.Update();
}
```

If you are uploading a file, the first link will be useful. If it is just a plain list item, the second link (and the code I pasted here) might be useful.

Good luck!